# How to reuse obj-c block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://aaa"
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseJSON) {
      ...
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [[TWMessageBarManager sharedInstance]
            showMessageWithTitle:@"Network connection failure"
                     description:@"Please check your network"
                            type:TWMessageBarMessageTypeError];
    }];
```

Some block is constant, can be used repeatedly. For example here's failure block, How can I  reuse this block for reduce the amount of code?

I hope it is a global reuse, rather than the current context, so I can store it as a property? Or get_method()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the block to a variable, then you can pass that around:

```
void (^failureBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) = ^void(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { /* write what you want */ };

void (^successBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseJSON) = ^void(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseJSON) { /* write what you want */ };
```

Then you can use it in further calls like this:

```
[manager GET:@"" success:successBlock failure: failureBlock];
```

Bonus: [Check out this guide](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com).

Comment: I hope it is a global reuse, rather than the current context, so I can store it as a property? Or get method?

Comment: @zicjin The scope of the block variable is just inside where you declare it (in other words, until it sees the next `}`). Yes you can store it as a property or as a global context.

Answer (score 3):

you can save it like a variable like so:

```
void(^blockname)(AFHTTPRequestOperation*, NSError*) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [[TWMessageBarManager sharedInstance]
        showMessageWithTitle:@"Network connection failure"
                 description:@"Please check your network"
                        type:TWMessageBarMessageTypeError];
}
```

then just put `blockname` for the failure parameter instead of the whole thing

Comment: I hope it is a global reuse, rather than the current context, so I can store it as a property? Or get_method?

Comment: yep you can use it as a property or anything that a normal variable can be

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, instead of reuse blocks, you should consider reuse the whole function

```
- (void)getURLPath:(NSString *)urlPath withSuccessBlock:(void (^)(id responseJSON))block {
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:urlPath
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseJSON) {
      ...
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [[TWMessageBarManager sharedInstance]
            showMessageWithTitle:@"Network connection failure"
                     description:@"Please check your network"
                            type:TWMessageBarMessageTypeError];
    }];
}
```